# Drawing boundary lines based on kmeans cluster centres

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm quite new to scikit learn, but wanted to try an interesting project.

I have longitude and latitudes for points in the UK, which I used to create cluster centers using scikit learns KMeans class. To visualise this data, rather than having the points as clusters, I wanted to instead draw boundaries around each cluster. For example, if one cluster was London and the other Oxford, I currently have a point at the center of each city, but I was wondering if there's a way to use this data to create a boundary line based on my clusters instead?

Here is my code so far to create the clusters:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

location1="XXX"
df = pd.read_csv(location1, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

#Run kmeans clustering
X = df[['long','lat']].values #~2k locations in the UK
y=df['label'].values   #Label is a 0 or 1
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=30, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
centers=kmeans.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1], marker='s', s=100)
```

So I would like to be able to convert the centers in the above example to lines that demarcate each of the regions -- is this possible?

Thanks,

Anant

Comment: I would suggest drawing Voronoi diagram, there should definitely be a python library for that.

Comment: are you asking about spatial boundaries? For example - draw boundaries for the city, where the centroid lies (belongs to)? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53918/is-there-a-way-to-put-a-separate-line-between-clusters-for-k-means-clustering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're talking about spatial boundaries, in this case you should follow Bunyk's recommendation and use a Voronoi Diagram [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram)]. Here is a practical demonstration of what you could achieve: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/pv/8037100.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scipi to generate a Voronoi Diagram. [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html)

For your code it would be

```py
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

location1="XXX"
df = pd.read_csv(location1, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

#Run kmeans clustering
X = df[['long','lat']].values #~2k locations in the UK
y=df['label'].values   #Label is a 0 or 1
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=30, random_state=0).fit(X, y)
centers=kmeans.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(centers[:,0],centers[:,1], marker='s', s=100)


vor = Voronoi(centers)
fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor,plt.gca())

plt.show()
```