# Getting the boundaries of decision from K-Means (Voronoi cells)

Tags: python, geolocation, k-means, computational-geometry, voronoi

I have an implementation of K-means which returns clusters. Said cluster are to tesselate a city. What I'm interested is in getting the boundary of each cluster, the voronoi cells. My code is as follows:

```
class K_Means:
  def __init__(self, k=2, tol=0.001, max_iter=300):
      self.k = k
      self.tol = tol
      self.max_iter = max_iter

  def fit(self,data):

      self.centroids = {}

      for i in range(self.k):
          self.centroids[i] = data[i]

      for i in range(self.max_iter):
          self.classifications = {}

          for i in range(self.k):
              self.classifications[i] = []

          for featureset in data:
              distances = [np.linalg.norm(featureset-self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
              classification = distances.index(min(distances))
              self.classifications[classification].append(featureset)

          prev_centroids = dict(self.centroids)

          for classification in self.classifications:
              self.centroids[classification] = np.average(self.classifications[classification],axis=0)

          optimized = True

          for c in self.centroids:
              original_centroid = prev_centroids[c]
              current_centroid = self.centroids[c]
              if np.sum((current_centroid-original_centroid)/original_centroid*100.0) > self.tol:
                  print(np.sum((current_centroid-original_centroid)/original_centroid*100.0))
                  optimized = False

          if optimized:
              break

  def predict(self,data):
      distances = [np.linalg.norm(data-self.centroids[centroid]) for centroid in self.centroids]
      classification = distances.index(min(distances))
      return classification

X = df[['order_latitude', 'order_longitude']].to_numpy()
# plt.scatter(*zip(*X))
model = K_Means()
model.fit(X)
```

And my dataframe like this:

```
    order_latitude  order_longitude
0   38.3477022  -0.4927108
1   38.3624854  -0.4809995
2   38.3416865  -0.5005017
3   38.347822   -0.4882809
4   38.3511359  -0.4866966
5   38.3603331  -0.4869405
6   38.3433719  -0.4964212
7   38.3507314  -0.5098433
8   38.3576242  -0.4829199
9   38.3624383  -0.4878071
10  38.3511359  -0.4866966
```

I correctly creates the cluster, but I'm unable to create the boundaries. I cannot use a library for k-means, as even though my example shows the usual norm, in the real one I need to use distances not implemented in any library I know (the travelling time between nodes). I tried using scipy Voronoi, but the data is sparse in the geography, it doesnt tesellate. Other related questions as this  [Drawing boundary lines based on kmeans cluster centres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347738/drawing-boundary-lines-based-on-kmeans-cluster-centresper) have a promising answer, but again I can't fit my own metric and it clusters in an unwanted way.

Comment: What's wrong with scipy Voronoi ?

Comment: I cannot specify which norm I must use

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that with a custom norm, you are on your own.

If you are able to obtain the equations of a circle, of the bisector of two points and the circumcenter of three points (intersection of the three bisectors), you can craft a brute-force algorithm that works by enumerating all point-free circumcircles (this is an O(n^4) process :-( ), giving the Voronoi vertices, and by joining the circumcircles with a common pair of points, you get the Voronoi edges.

Comment: How would you get it using the usual euclid distances? I'm having troubles getting it from my own script